# Updating text after input changes

Tags: angularjs

[System Link](http://thea-team.my/NgInvoice/AJSinvoice/)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matsom/87f7201j/)

After selecting item (which is from database and return item's price and updated on cost column), i would like Total column to update according to the price that has been return before.

However, after several trial using event (ng-click, focus, etc) Total column still fail to update.

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="row invoice-item" data-ng-repeat="item in invoice.items" ng-animate="'slide-down'">
    <div class="col-xs-1 remove-item-container">
      <a href ng-hide="printMode" ng-click="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger">[X]</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 input-container">
      <input ng-model="item.description" placeholder="Item Name" size="35" list="myBuku" id="item_{{$index}}" ng-keyup="suggest(item.description)" ng-blur="check(item.description, $event)"/>
      <datalist id="myBuku">
      </datalist>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 input-container">
      <input ng-model="item.qty" value="1" size="4" ng-required ng-validate="integer" placeholder="Quantity"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 input-container">
      <input ng-model="item.cost" id="money_{{$index}}" value="0.00" ng-focus="focusMoney(item.description, $event)" ng-required ng-validate="number" size="6" placeholder=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right input-container">
      {{item.cost * item.qty | currency: currencySymbol}}
      <input type="text" ng-model="total" bound-model="item.qty * item.cost"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

function use to update input on cost column.

```
    $scope.focusMoney = function(barang, obj){
  var elm = angular.element(obj.currentTarget);
  var elmId = elm.attr('id');
  $http({
    method: "POST",
    url : './hargaBarang.php',
    data: {barang: barang},
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}
  }).success(function(response){
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector("#"+elmId) ).val(response);
    console.log(myEl);
  });
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: The request itself works, but the server return `Data not found`.

Comment: Most probably you need to double click the item input field (will give you list of data from database)